# Finding a linear 1-error-correcting code

Tags: coding-theory

"Find a linear $1$-error-correcting code $C$ of length $12$ satisfying the following conditions or disprove its existence.

(1) The number of words of $C$ is $256$.

(2) The word $c = 111110000011$ belongs to $C$.

(3) The word $c' = 000111000101$ does not belong to $C$ but can be corrected
to a word of $C$."

I know that, if such a code exists, then the distance between any two codewords must be at least $3$. I also see that the distance between $c$ and $c'$ is $6$, and since the code is $1$-error-correcting, $c'$ contains exactly $1$ error. But I'm not sure how to make use of condition (1). Any hints?

Comment: Are sure you got the data right? but I don't see an elegant solution, it seems possible to me, but my solution is not very instructive, for a homework.

Comment: Hint: Have you heard about _Hamming_ codes? There exists a linear 1-error-correcting binary code of length $15$ with $2^{11}$ codewords. It is the Hamming code of length $15$ and is a $11$-dimensional subspace of the vector space of $15$-bit binary vectors.  Consider the codewords of this code with the property that the first $3$ bits are all $0$.  Is this a _subspace_ of the $11$-dimensional space that is the Hamming code? and if it is indeed a subspace, what is the dimension of this subspace?